# Can we change font color of current page of pagingNavigation in wicket framework?

Tags: html, css, pagination, wicket

We use pagingNavigation of wicket framework, but when I click any no. Of navigation bar, it fetch datatable, but we got confuse on which page we are right now,so recognising actual page I want to change color of that clicked number. Is there any way to achive this thing ?

Comment: What is wicket? Do you have any examples?

Comment: Wicket is framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link for the current page has `disabled="disabled"` attribute. You could use CSS to change its color:

```
.navigator a[disabled] {
  color: #123456;
}
```

Comment: Can we use this scenario for radio button?? Radio button can have disable attribute?

Comment: Sure! It should be something like `.navigator input[type=radio][disabled] {color: #123456;}`